# How to use buildTypes, productFlavors, and sourceSet to batch build apks for different android channels

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, apk

I'm new to **unity3d** , and I have to use it to batch build different **apks** for multiple android channels. I have to change project's package name, app name, icon, and meta-data values defined in AndroidManifest.xml, which is really boring me. What's worse is that I have to depend on different **sdks** that makes the project so heavy.

I know that android studio now is using **gradle** which can use buildTypes, productFlavors and sourceSet, manifestPlaceHolder, applicationId and some other configures to build different apks for multiple android channel.

I also find some plugins in github like https://github.com/zasadnyy/unity-gradle-plugin, but it can't use buildTypes or productFlavors features.

I wonder if it is possible to use gradle to achieve my goal? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Unity's gradle support is substandard (as of Unity 2017 and possibly beyond). I would recommend using the [Build Player Pipeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html) in combination with your own [Post Process Build](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Callbacks.PostProcessBuildAttribute.html) code to selectively enable or disable features and configure the output. You can configure the specific build using [Custom Scripting Directives](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityCloudBuildCustomScriptingDefineDirectives.html) that can be modified in the `Build Settings` -> `Player Settings` panel when building the application.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're searching for, but you can also script the Unity build process to achieve the same thing.

You can do custom build with a combination of [build pipeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html) and [executing scripts from the command line](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html).